# How to log detailed errors in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, debugging, laravel-5

In Laravel 5, when there's an error, you will see a message thrown in the browser:
Whoops, looks like something went wrong, follwed "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found".

Is there a way to throw these messages to the log file as well? Currently it only states generic messages of no debug value.

I've attempted to put Log::info('There's an error at this location'); in the functions that I believe should be firing, but they do not show up.

Comment: If this is for your dev environment have a look at https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar - it's great for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

`Log::info()` will only write the given message to a log file.

To show it in a browser, you have to render it separately.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How does he render is separately? I highly recommend improving your post and adding an example as it really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!